# Editing Gist with cURL: "Problems parsing JSON",

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -v \

  --request PATCH \
  --data "$(
    printf '{"files": {"somefile.json": {"content": " {"field": "value"} "}}}' \
    )" \
  --user x:x \
  https://api.github.com/gists/x
```

Tried adding --header "Content-Type: application/json", no luck.

I'm using this because the content is actually a command output but right now I'm testing the basics because this is not workig.

I believe is somethig related to double quote escaping in bash, tried for a couple of hours with no luck. This is a nightmare.

Any tip is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus thanks! but: $ shellcheck myscript No issues detected! :/

Comment: Why didn't you update your first question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57634219/7939871 ?
If you did not go there already, I point you to the gist edit github API documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla: Why do I see a blank line after `curl` and shellcheck, too?

Comment: @Cyrus there is a space but neither the bash script nor spellcheck.net cares. Corrected on sc.net and still no issues.

Comment: @LéaGris because the questions are similar but not equal. This is more related to how Github parses the string I provided with your help. Already read the docs, little help as there is no Json example.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla I updated my answer here with very important information https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634322/7939871 To sum-it up, I fixed the content string escaping by using `jq`, but I still fail to update a gist, even a public and non-anonymous gist, as the API answer HTTP 404 not found. gist update in GitHub API is so poorly documented. Anyway I hope you will have more success. The implementation I provide is JSON conform and AFAIK conform to the GitHub API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have too many quotation marks. If you want the value of the "content" element to be an object, then instead of this:

```
"content": " {"field": "value"} "
```

try this:

```
"content": {"field": "value"}
```

On the off chance that you want it to be a string, then try this:

```
"content": " {\"field\": \"value\"} "
```

Comment: The content is the actual gist file content, not an object. It can be anything if type text string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting against quote escaping, you could write your payload to a file and tell curl to use that file as data like so:

```
curl -v \
  --request PATCH \
  --data @/tmp/some/file \
  --user x:x \
  https://api.github.com/gists/x
```

Note the `@` sign in the `--data` argument, which tells curl that the rest of the argument is a file name to read data from.

Depending on how you create your payload, you could also pipe it to curl using `-` as filename (`echo payload | curl --data @- ...`)

Comment: Thanks, but same output from the GIT API, problems parsing JSON.

Comment: Please check if the contents of your JSON file are actually valid JSON, easiest with an online JSON validator, e.g. https://www.jsonformatter.io/

Comment: Yes, it's valid.